# Setting associations in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Im a little rusty to Rails and I'm trying to find an appropriate way to set a series of has_and_belongs_to_many associations. I have created a method, which I intend to make private, which sets the associations.

```
  def update

    def set_associations
        industriesParams = params[:business][:industry_ids].reject{ |c| c.empty? }
        @business.update(:industry_ids => industriesParams)
    end

        @business = Business.find(params[:id])
        @business.set_associations

  end
```

In this attempt, I am getting "undefined method `set_associations'" which I don't quite get. But I am also seeking a cleaner way of setting the associations from scratch.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You sould simply place it outside of your block

Comment: have u put the set_associations method in your update method, i think we cannot do that, please take it out and try it would work

Comment: Thanks guys. Although, when I define the method in the under private at the bottom of the file, I still am being returned `undefined method set_associations' for #<Business:0x007f99b8bbf888>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work :

```
def update
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  set_associations  
end

private

def set_associations
  industriesParams = params[:business][:industry_ids].reject{ |c| c.empty? }
  @business.update(:industry_ids => industriesParams)
end
```

But to make things shorter, you could even write the following :

```
def update
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  industriesParams = params[:business][:industry_ids].reject{ |c| c.empty? }
  @business.update(:industry_ids => industriesParams)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, however, I am still being returned `undefined method set_associations' for #<Business:0x007f99b8bbf888>` . Any other ideas?

Comment: Obviously; my bad. You just need to call the method as it is, i've esited the answer

Comment: Yeah this works but the whole reason I'm writing the method is so that I can re-use, and also I have a bunch of other associations that I need to make in the same way. Any idea why the method isn't working here?

Comment: Oh, when I call the function separately from the object, it seems to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: For sure it has nothing to do with the object; again sorty for this error. Glad it helped; please accept the answer if  you have time! Best